# Calculating averages over specific time period with two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

So I have two dataframes, one with customerIDs, start_period and end_period, as well as some other columns that are irrelevant for the question. The other has the customerID, the month and how much the customer spent in that month.

Examples of the dataframes are:

```
df_period = pd.DataFrame({'customerID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     'start_period': ['2023-01', '2023-01', '2023-03', '2023-02', '2023-05'],
     'end_period': ['2023-05', '2023-07', '2023-04', '2023-05', '2023-12']})
df_spent = pd.DataFrame({'customerID': [1], 'month': ['2023-01', '2023-02', '2023-03', '2023-04', '2023-05']
     'average_spent': [150, 200, 100, 300, 250]})
```

The output should be added to df_period as a new column called average_spent. Does anybody know how I could do this?